# Laplace Transform for an Initial Value Problem

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method, laplace-expansion

I think I have this one all figured out, I just need someone to tell me if I got it or not...

so I have:

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> 9y''+12y'+4y = e^{-2t}\\
> \\
> y(0)=y'(0)=1
> \end{cases}
> $$

so using the usual method, where $L[f'']=s^{2}F(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$

and $L[f']=sF(s)-sf(0)$

I managed to get to

$(9s^{2}+12s+4)F(s)-30=\frac{1}{s+2}$

and thus

$F(s) = \frac{31}{(s+2)(3s+2)^{2}}$

using partial fractions, I eventually get down to

$\frac{31}{(s+2)(3s+2)^{2}} = \frac{31/16}{s+2}-\frac{93/48}{3s+2}+\frac{93/4}{(3s+2)^{2}}$

and therefore:

$F(s)=\frac{31}{16}e^{-2t}-\frac{93}{48}e^{-2/3t}+\frac{93}{4}te^{-2t}$

Is this alright?? If no, where did I go wrong?? I usually have suspicions that I got something wrong when the constants are very large, like I have right here

thanks very much, in advance

-GD

Comment: I think you might be missing a $3$ next to the $e^{-\frac{2}{3}t}$ term. Use [Wolframs Laplace Transform](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=122507de3372c73f916a1d07ccb9cf9c&title=Laplace+Transform+Calculator&theme=blue&i0=cos) to check.

Comment: Sounds like a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not correct $L[f']=sF(s)-sf(0)$. It should be $L[f']=sF(s)-f(0)$

Then here you cant have 31 at the numerator with

$$(9s^{2}+12s+4)F(s)-30=\frac{1}{s+2}$$

Should be

$$F(s)=\frac{30s+61}{(s+2)(3s+2)^2}=\frac{1}{(s+2)(3s+2)^2}+\frac{30}{(3s+2)^2}$$

Another mistake you did is that it is not 31 but rather $9s+21$

So you should have this instead:

$$(9s^{2}+12s+4)F(s) \color{red}{-9s-21}=\frac{1}{s+2}$$
$$F(s)=\frac{1}{(s+2)(3s+2)^2}+\frac{3(3s+7)}{(3s+2)^2}$$
$$.......$$
***Edit***

$$\frac{3(3s+7)}{(3s+2)^2}=\frac{3(3s+2)}{(3s+2)^2}+\frac{15}{(3s+2)^2}=\frac{1}{(s+\frac 2 3)}+\frac 5 3\frac{1}{(s+\frac 2 3)^2}$$

$$\implies e^{-\frac {2t} 3}+\frac 5 3 te^{-\frac {2t} 3}$$

For the first fraction try to find A B C such that:
$$\frac{1}{(s+2)(3s+2)^2}=\frac{A}{(s+2)}+\frac{B}{(3s+2)}+\frac{C}{(3s+2)^2}$$

Comment: thanks heaps Isham, I'm at work now but I will check it later and see what I get. Much love!

Comment: Yeah everyhting seems correct to me except for that 31 at the numerator..You were almost done..

Comment: ok, so I've revisited it just now and you were absolutely correct, I left out that 9s... so considering this, I used the same principles as before, I got down to:

$\frac{1+(9s+21)(s+2)}{(s+2)(3s+2)^{2}}=\frac{17/2}{s+2}-\frac{45/2}{3s+2}+\frac{99/2}{(3s+2)^{2}$


and then that lead me to:

$F(s)=\frac{17}{2}e^{-2t}-\frac{45}{6}e^{-2/3t}+\frac{99}{2}te^{-2t}$

Comment: Hi Georges...Yes you were almost there except for the 9 s... I need to do the calculation again to check your annswer...

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriou I added some insights in my post....